# How can one add drop shadows to Raphael.js objects?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I would like to find out how to add blurry edged drop shadows to Raphael.js objects/paths. As far as I know it is not possible with the library as is but is there a work around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a link to Raphael.blur in a separate answer, per the OP's request.

http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/plugins/raphael.blur.js

Updated code sample:

```
var shadow = canvas.path(p);
shadow.attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#555", translation: "4,4"});
shadow.blur(4);
var shape = canvas.path(p);
```

Note that in Dmitry's comments he mentions that there is no WebKit support. He uses the `<filter>` element and the feGaussianBlur filter effect. WebKit has implemented the feGaussianBlur effect, but filters are [unstable](http://webkit.org/projects/svg/status.xml) and are disabled in Safari (it may work in Chrome 5 - should definitely work in Chrome 6).

Comment: Is the `.blur` function undocumented? Can't find it anywhere on the Raphael docs. Or is it native?

Comment: It is a Raphael plugin. You can get it at the link above and include it in your page after raphael.js.

Comment: The URL to the plugin seems to be broken (getting a 404), anyone got a working link?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/webdesks/source/browse/trunk/DmitryBaranovskiy-raphael-5b9602d/plugins/?r=9

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `Element.glow([glow])` to get a shadow effect. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.glow

Comment: +1 that worked for me. I'm doing a generic bubble widget using Raphael and jQuery. This helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, didn't think of using glow.  The defaults for glow are a black colour with a 0.5 opacity which would suggest that it's intended to be used for drawing drop-shadows.

Comment: The link in this answer is now inactive. I think you now need to use a plugin instead.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a plugin that adds a drop shadow to an element by applying an SVG filter to it.
It's based on the blur plugin.

You can find it here: https://github.com/dahoo/raphael.dropshadow.js

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is simply to draw the object with a shadow-colored fill, offset by a few pixels, and then draw the actual object on top.

```
var shadow = canvas.path(p);
shadow.attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#555", translation: "4,4"});
var shape = canvas.path(p);
```

You can also adjust the opacity attribute if needed.

Comment: but a shadow colored fill will have a solid edge. I am looking for an edge that blurry, from light gray to 0% alpha. you know?

Comment: Raphael does have a blur plugin. I've never used it, so I can't vouch for it, but it's by Dmitry so we can assume he knows what he's doing ;-)  http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/plugins/raphael.blur.js

Comment: Oh that is interesting. You should submit it as an answer and I will accept it. If you don't then I will answer it myself with in 3 days. Thanks. Still drop shadow should be coded into Raphael to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a glow to add shadows.

`.glow({ color: '#900', width:10, offsetx:5 }) // random example...`

check out the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.glow)