# Adding glow/border to edge of only the non-transparent portion of an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, transparency, border, bitmapdata

I'm trying to come up with a way to mimik something we were previously doing in Adobe Flash using some sort of Bitmap Filter but instead with pure javascript.

Previously we had a set of PNG images w/ transparency around the core image. When an image was clicked, a soft glow (ala border) would be added around the non-transparent portion of the image, slightly consuming some of the transparency but the majority of the outer transparent portion would remain transparent.

W/ javascript I can easily add a border around the entire image when clicked, but that is not what I am aiming for. I only want a border around the non-transparent portion of the image.

I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with image manipulation techniques, so I'm curious if there is a way I could achieve this using the various JS image manipulation libs out there ala [BitmapData](http://peternitsch.net/bitmapdata.js/) or [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/). Taking a look at both of these I wonder if there is something I could do w/ edge detection, glowing effects, and overlays...

Comment: `I only want a border around the non-transparent portion of the image.` It is impossible to do it with js. Only if a replacement image is already prepared. Canvas is not really a solution (if you need compatibility) and all these 'calculations' will take resources and time.

Comment: Thanks Cheery, this is what I feared. Canvas "could" be a future possibility. Sounds like I'll be better off either using replacement images or using vector variants of my images (which makes pretty much anything possible).

Comment: BTW, if you'd change your comment to an "Answer" I'd be glad to mark it as correct  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Raphael (or are willing to use it), you might consider using Dmitry's [blur plugin](http://code.google.com/p/webdesks/source/browse/trunk/DmitryBaranovskiy-raphael-5b9602d/plugins/raphael.blur.js?r=9).  Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878436/how-can-one-add-drop-shadows-to-raphael-js-objects), I was able to achieve the glow effect I think you're looking for by adding another image behind the one I'd like "glowed".  The background image is blurred, giving a "glow" or "halo" around the crisp image on top.

Sample code:

```
var img = this.R.image("yourImage.png", 0, 0, 50, 50);
var glow = img.clone().toBack();
glow.blur(5);
```

The plugin includes the caveat that there's no WebKit support. It seems that there is now *some* WebKit support as it works in Chrome (I'm running 18.0) but not Safari (I'm running 5.1.5).

Comment: Also FYI, Safari 6+ now correctly supports SVG filters (which is what Raphael's blur uses) so this is supported in all the major browsers, including IE8.

Answer (score 0):

`I only want a border around the non-transparent portion of the image.`

It is impossible to do it with js. Only if a replacement image is already prepared. Canvas is not really a solution (if you need compatibility) and all these 'calculations' will take resources and time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's entirely suitable for your situation, but there are tools out there to convert Flash to HTML (e.g. [Swiffy](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)).  I suspect they can be flaky at times, but it's something to consider :)