# Raphael blur plugin

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one add drop shadows to Raphael.js objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878436/how-can-one-add-drop-shadows-to-raphael-js-objects)

I see here:

[How to use svg filters with raphael js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485115/how-to-use-svg-filters-with-raphael-js)

that a blur plugin has been created for Raphael although it has now disappeared from gitHub. Does anyone know of similar plugins? Or perhaps another method to utilise svg filters in raphael.

The raphael.glow() function is not suitable for what I want.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks Erik. I have resolved this using the blur plugin from Dmitry and the dropshadow plugin from dahoo https://github.com/dahoo/raphael.dropshadow.js, this is a simple enough template to use missing SVG functionality. Although safari still only supports SVG filters nightly in builds.